# Counting the number of co-occurrences during a given time window using Redis

Tags: redis

So I have a set of users and a set of websites. For a given user, I know which website he visited and when. I am interested in building an API using `Redis` to answer questions in the form: "How many unique days are contained in the browsing history of user `u` for website `w` during a time window `[t0, t1]`"? Let's call that number `f(u,w,t0,t1)`. Each day is identified by an integer `d` (e.g., the number of days since EPOCH)

I see two ways to model the browsing data using `Redis`:

- create a `sorted set` for each pair `( u, w )`. Each element of the sorted set is `( score=d, element=d )` where `d` is the day when `u` visited `w`. In other words, a set element is identical to its score. Then `f(u,w,t0,t1)` is simply `ZCOUNT( u:w, t0, t1 )`
- create a `set` for each pair `( u, w )`. Each element of the set is `d`. Then to get `f(u,w,t0,t1)`, I need to iterate over the set and count the number of days between `t0` and `t1`

My current understanding is that there is a compromise between memory usage and speed (to answer a query): the first solution is the fastest (I don't have to iterate over the whole set), although it is wasting memory (the same number `d` is used both as the score and the set element).

My questions are:

- is my understanding correct?
- are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct... but here's an optimization to the 2nd approach that is likely to perform better: provided `t0` and `t1` to query for, build a temporary set that contains all `d` values between these. Then, do an SINTERSTORE between that temporary set and the one for `(u,w)`. To obtain the count, SCARD the resulting set.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your suggestion and used `SINTERSTORE`. It actually returns the cardinality of the set intersection, so the `SCARD` was not necessary.